# How can i obtain the value of the body of a candle in Pinescript V5, i looked at the documentation and internet but all soultions offered are outdated

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

I would like to obtain the value BodyRange, to then input into strategy.entry in order to set a stoploss that would look something like this:

```
strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, stop=body - stoploss, limit=body + takeprofit)
```

"body" is the name of the variable that would get the BodyRange info.

I'm very new to pinescript so thanks for any help!

I tried to use the BodyRange()[1] function but the compiler says that such function does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot just randomly type function names and expect them to exist. There is no `BodyRange()` in `pinescript`.

You can easily calculate the body with `math.abs(open - close)`.